# Can't open Excel file in a browser SharePoint 2013 on-premise

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, excel, office

I'm using:
Office 2016,SharePoint 2013 on-premise,Ax 2012 R2

I want to open Excel file in Sharepoint folder, but I have an error

> We’re sorry. We ran into a problem completing your request. Please try that again in few minutes.

Searching for an answer and find this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31128.excel-services-issue-in-sharepoint-20132010.aspx) But is is not help me.
That I want to see my logs and there I find errors, but I don't know how to fix them

> 06/01/2017 17: 46: 52.60 w3wp.exe (0x0E80) 0x1CF8 Excel Services
>   Application Excel Calculation Services d51d Medium
>   MossHost.CreateServiceChannel : Failed with the
>   following exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP
>   request is not allowed For the client authentication scheme
>   "Negotiate". The authentication header "NTLM" is received from the
>   server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
>   error: (401) Unauthorized. In System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse ()
>   in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply
>   (TimeSpan timeout) --- End of trace of internal exception stack ---
>   Server stack trace: in System.ServiceModel.
>   Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication (HttpWebRequest
>   request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException,
>   HttpChannelFactory1 factory) ... 1968f79d-ffc6-c09e-71e7-ebd58601bd96

Comment: Disable office modern authentification https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206623/sharepoint-2016-adfs-persistent-cookie-office-client-integration-authent [Microsoft support documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3203432/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforsharepointserver2016june13-2017)

Answer (score 0):

I have three questions that might help me confirm the issue.

1. Are you using Explorer View when trying to open the excel file?
2. What are you permissions on the document? Read, Contribute, Full Access, or something else?
3. Does this happen for all users on all libraries when trying to open Excel documents?

I've seen this error when a user tries to open a document while in Explorer View and they do not have the proper permission level on the document or library. If this is happening for all users when trying to open an excel document from a library, then I would look at the permissions that your Excel Services Application Service Account has on the database server.

Comment: 1)Yes, i'm looking to the files in a browser.
2)I have full permissions on the documents and folders.
3)Yes, thi is happens to all users(admins, and any user) and I'm trying many documents,not one