# Outlook 2016 + ADFS 2.0 + SharePoint 2016, Sync Calendar causing prompt for credentials

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, authentication, outlook, adfs

Our clients are having problems with Sync'd Calendars they have connected in their outlook from SharePoint 2016.  In SharePoint 2013, if they failed to sync it would silently fail.  (Typically, this was due to the Auth Token expiring because outlook was unable to actually log into the ADFS with windows integrated auth like the IE browser).

Software involved:

- Outlook 2016 / Win 10
- SharePoint 2016
- ADFS 2.0, Windows Integrated Auth enabled.

All Sites are in the local intranet zone on the PC, and in IE it will automatically log in as expected through the ADFS server and into SharePoint.

Description of configuration:

SharePoint has 2 zones.

- Default - Windows Claims + Trusted Auth. + ADFS
- Intranet - ADFS 2.0 Claims / Trusted Identity Provider Only.

The url for the default zone is https://blah-win.domain.com, the url for the Intranet is https://blah.domain.com  (and we cannot change these).

Clients access https://blah.domain.com and locate a calendar within SharePoint and click the Sync with Outlook button.  This installs the calendar to their outlook and it works for a while.  Eventually the auth token expires and Outlook is unable to re-auth.  It will work again if the client visits the site and logs in.

When outlook does a Send & Receive, it the auth token isn't estabolished by an IE visit, it will prompt for credentials.  However, outlook will not use the credentials it just asks for them over and over again.

We need to either:

- Enable silently failing of authentication until the user auths against the site.
- Fix outlook so that it can auth against ADFS much the same how IE does.

Suggestions appreciated =)

Comment: Similar to https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206623/sharepoint-2016-adfs-persistent-cookie-office-client-integration-authent