# Access SharePoint 2016 server using Python

Tags: 2016, authentication

I want to download a file from my sharepoint 2016 server using Python.

I am using the requests module, but if another module is better, can use that one instead.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

headers = {'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'}
auth = HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password")
r = requests.get("https://example.sharepoint.com/_api/web", auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

But my request gets redirected to my https://example.sharepoint.com/my.policy page with HTML data that contains the following:

Session Expired/Timeout Due to user inactivity, your session expired. Click the following link to start a new session.

I also tried:

```
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
auth = HttpNtlmAuth("username", "password")
r = requests.get("https://example.sharepoint.com/_api/web", auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

but got the same redirect to .

This seems similar to the authentication prompt issue described in this SE:
[SharePoint 2016 - ADFS - persistent cookie - office client integration - authentication prompt](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206623/sharepoint-2016-adfs-persistent-cookie-office-client-integration-authent)

I think I need to include an authentication cookie with my request somehow, but 
I could be wrong.
Any idea what the authentication/persistant cookie object looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to request an auth token from the service. There is a good sample project here.

[Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client)

Comment: Using Office365-REST-Python-Client worked for me. This module seems to handle the auth token needed for Sharepoint 2016 whereas my solutions didn't.